# How to get offline messages from openfire in android application

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to build a small chat application in android using asmack API and XMPP.
Online chat is working but i don't know  how to get off-line messages from openfire server.
if you have any kind of solution regarding this question,please help me........!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offline messages get delivered automatically from the server to the client when you login the next time and send your online presence. There is no additional coded needed on the client to retrieve them.

Comment: How to send user online presence?

Comment: Once you logged in, the client will send a presence online. If you want to send manually you can send like:- connection.sendStanza(Presence(Presence.Type.available))                   where connection is XMPP connection object